# Discuss the main issues governing concurrency control in a large distributed database environment

Tags: database, oracle, distributed-database, dbms-job

I'm revising for uni using mock questions and I'm wondering where I could find materials or information to answer this question or if someone could walk me through it?

Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is for solving reproducible specific programming issues - not general open ended "discuss..." questions.

Answer (score 0):

Ever hear of the "2-Phase Commit" algorithm?  That's how they do it.  Incidentally, I met the guy who has the patent on "2-Phase Commit"; he's an old-timer like me :).

Comment: Actually it's one of the ways they do it. There's CDC, store-and-forward  and of course, since 12cR2, sharding (dread word).